# Querying items that have a date/time within the next 20 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on generating a notification when new items are added to a table.

The table will be a filtered version of the [OrderTasks] Table.  Using microsoft Power Automate i will generate a notification to be sent to the user when items require action within the next fifteen minutes.

I am using the below query but i am getting empty results.

i have tried multiple other recommendations on here but have been unsuccessful

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[OrderTasks]
WHERE  (dbo.OrderTasks.ActionDate BETWEEN DATEADD(HH, 0, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(MI, 20, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Perhaps your dates in the database are being save in UTC time, which is usually a standard practice. Instead of `GETDATE()` try `GETUTCDATE()`. Also, it seems you have an extra parenthesis. Use this: `(dbo.OrderTasks.ActionDate BETWEEN GETUTCDATE() AND DATEADD(MI, 20, GETUTCDATE())`.

Comment: the time is being stored in my local time and  when i used your code it told me i was missing a )

Comment: Sorry, edited: `(dbo.OrderTasks.ActionDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(MI, 20, GETDATE()))`

Comment: @AlexBehrmann Then add the `)`.

Comment: @AlexBehrmann . . . Please show sample data.  Your query looks like it should be doing what you want.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RXzklEAlVNeiDwpGys5zXQWF7MfRV56E

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[OrderTasks]
WHERE  ActionDate >= GetDate() and ActionDate <= DateAdd(MINUTE, 20, GetDate())
```

Comment: it returned a blank result.

i tried this on a table with larger data and i found  
SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[Orders]
  WHERE  SLACompletionDate >= GetDate() and SLACompletionDate <= DateAdd(MI, 30, GetDate())

it returned items that are due at 17:15 -17:26 and it was 12:05